# BeautifulSoup not getting web data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm creating a web scraper in order to pull the name of a company from a chamber of commerce website directory.

Im using BeautifulSoup. The page and soup objects appear to be working, but when I scrape the HTML content, an empty list is returned when it should be filled with the directory names on the page.

Web page trying to scrape: https://www.austinchamber.com/directory

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul> class="item-list item-list--small"> == $0
    <li>
      <div class='item-content'>
        <div class='item-description'>
          <h5 class = 'h5'>Women Helping Women LLC</h5>
```

Here is the python code:

```
def pageRequest(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    return page

def htmlSoup(page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    return soup

def getNames(soup):
    name = soup.find_all('h5', class_='h5')
    return name

page = pageRequest("https://www.austinchamber.com/directory")
soup = htmlSoup(page)
name = getNames(soup)
for n in name:
    print(n)
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to scrape a dynamic website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically via Ajax. To get the data, you can use this script:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.austinchamber.com/api/v1/directory?filter[categories]=&filter[show]=all&page={page}&limit=24'

page = 1

for page in range(1, 10):
    print('Page {}..'.format(page))
    data = requests.get(url.format(page=page)).json()

    # uncommentthis to print all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    for d in data['data']:
        print(d['title'])
```

Prints:

```
...

Indeed
Austin Telco Federal Credit Union - Taos
Green Bank
Seton Medical Center Austin
Austin Telco Federal Credit Union - Jollyville
Page 42..
Texas State SBDC - San Marcos Office
PlainsCapital Bank - Motor Bank
University of Texas - Thompson Conference Center
Lamb's Tire & Automotive Centers - #2 Research & Braker
AT&T Labs
Prosperity Bank - Rollingwood
Kerbey Lane Cafe - Central
Lamb's Tire & Automotive Centers - #9 Bee Caves
Seton Medical Center Hays
PlainsCapital Bank - North Austin
Ellis & Salazar Body Shop
aLamb's Tire & Automotive Centers - #6 Lake Creek
Rudy's Country Store and BarBQ

...
```